# What's the maximum safe power supply voltage through GPIO?

Tags: gpio, power-supply

What is the maximum safe voltage to supply to the RPi when powering it through the GPIO pins?

Due to size restraints in a project, I need to supply power to my RPi through the GPIO pins instead of the micro USB plug. I plan on using a UBEC that provides 5V@3A. However, when I measured it, I found it's actually outputing 5.3V.

From [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=45819) I read the RPi's "safe" input voltage range is 5V ±5% for a max safe voltage of 5.25V. Am I pushing it with 5.3V or should that be fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pi itself will be safe up to just less than 6V.  I would not approach that limit too closely.  Mine are often powered from circa 5.8V.

You would have to check any attached persipherals, e.g. USB, HDMI screen, on a case by case basis.  As you say USB devices expect 4.75V to 5.25V.  My USB wireless dongles work fine.

I'd be shocked if problems arose from a 5.3V supply.